# Android: Intercept HTTP form POST response with ACTION_VIEW intent-filter

Tags: android, android-intent, http-post, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, intentfilter

I've set up an intent-filter to be triggered when a user downloads a file with a certain MIME-type in the built-in browser, my application is opened to handle it. I then receive the URI in the Intent's getData() field, which can be used to fetch the data. This seems odd, since to get the MIME type, the browser has obviously already at least started the HTTP request, but it's no big deal in the case of a simple HTTP GET -- in that case, I just re-fetch it and everything is fine.

However, if the desired content is coming as the result of a form post, I'm out of luck -- and I don't seem the be the only one, but I can't find any answers. Here are a couple of people asking similar questions with no response, and a Google ticket that seems to indicate that this was a hard limitation in older versions, but was fixed in Android 4.0 / Ice Cream Sandwich (which I'm using):

[Getting data from an implicit intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351563/getting-data-from-an-implicit-intent)

[Handling MIME type that is the result of a browser POST in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890926/handling-mime-type-that-is-the-result-of-a-browser-post-in-android)

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1780

Here is the intent-filter I'm using:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.WEB_SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE"/>
            <data android:host="*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/my-content-type"/>
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

The intent I get back contains no extras (getExtras() == null), the scheme is http (or https, as appropriate), the mimeType is "application/my-content-type" and the data is just the URL that was POSTed to.

I've tried using my Activity's `getContentResolver().query([theURI], null, null, null, null)`, but that returns null; I also tried `getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient([theURI])`, but that too returns null.

I also tried using the `getContentResolver().getInputStream([theURI])`, but that throws the following:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://[the form URL]
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:603)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:535)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:370)
    at my.package.MyActivity.onStart(MyActivity.java:127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1133)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4475)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1928)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So -- am I just missing something, or is this just a limitation of the framework?

Thanks.